# Ajax autocomplete based on usercode

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a webform with autocompletion. The user can fill in a personal code and the related fields will be shown in the form fields.

How can I fetch the results into my form fields?

What I tried so far:

1. Lookup the code in Javascript.
2. Use AJAX to send the code to PHP.
3. PHP looks up the code in the SQL query and fetches the result.
4. When I use the console and check the var_dump in the lookup_code() function I see the array from the user I want.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'ajax_lookup_userdata' );
/*
 * Ajax_lookup_userdata
 * Will check the string on the input field for the code.
 */

function ajax_lookup_userdata() {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

        /*Lookup the field value.*/
        var ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        var codeValue = jQuery('li.code input');
        var data;

        /* Limit the  keyup function... min characters and max characters. */
        $(codeValue).keyup(function(e){

            data = {
                'action': 'lookup_code',
                'codevalue': jQuery(this).val()
            };

            // This gives me the output of the values you insert into the code-textfield.
            console.log(data.codevalue);

            jQuery.post(ajax_url, data, function(response) {
                //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
               console.log(data);
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_lookup_code', 'lookup_code'); // for not logged in users


function lookup_code() {

global $wpdb;

$searchQuery = $_POST['codevalue'];

$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_contacts WHERE code LIKE "'.$searchQuery.'" ');

update_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', 'new_template.php' );
// Here are my values that I want to receive.
// How to pass them to the field values?
//var_dump($results[0]);

die();
}
```

The var_dumps($results[0]); gives me the following output:

```
object(stdClass)#277 (8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["code"]=>
  string(2) "1a"
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(4) "Bert"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(7) "Gibbers"
  ["street"]=>
  string(15) "Lazy Berry Edge"
  ["no"]=>
  string(2) "35"
  ["email"]=>
  string(18) "stone@meekness.com"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(12) "202-555-0102"
}
```

Thanks a lot for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill in the form as shown below:

```
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    // assign inputs[index] element values from the response.
}
```

This is pure JavaScript, unless I miss something.